# Grails data not saving

Tags: grails, groovy

In the basic CRUD model, from the create view, I have the following code to save an item:

```
println params
def newItem = new ProgressItem(name: params.name, comment: params.comment, status: params.status, itemsGroup: params.itemsGroup); //add itemsGroup: based on itemsGroup.id
newItem.save()

redirect(controller:'project', action:'show', id:params.itemsGroup.id) //change '1'
```

But it doesn't work, that is, when I am back at the project page there isn't another progress item added.

Here are the params that print out:

```
[status:FAILED, name:FF FF FF FF FF FF FF, itemsGroup.id:1, itemsGroup:[id:1], comment:FF FF FF FF FF FF FF, create:Create, action:save, controller:progressItem]
```

I don't get any errors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If instead of

```
newItem.save()
```

you do:

```
if( !newItem.save() ) {
   println "Validation errors on save"
   newItem.errors.each {
        println it
   }
}
```

Does it print out what was wrong?

Comment: Yeah I needed to perform ProgressGroup.get(params.itemsGroup.id) for the itemsGroup: